# .value_counts() when a condition on another column is fullfilled

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've been trying a bunch of different formulas and keep on getting errors.
df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Color': ['red','blue','red','red','green','red','yellow'],
        'Type': ['Oil', 'Aluminium', 'Oil', 'Oil', 'Cement Paint', 'Synthetic Rubber', 'Emulsion'],
        'Finish' : ['Satin', 'Matte', 'Matte', 'Satin', 'Semi-gloss', 'Satin', 'Satin'],
        'Use' : ['Interior', 'Exterior', 'Interior', 'Interior', 'Exterior', 'Exterior', 'Exterior'],
        'Price' : [55, 75, 60, 60, 55, 75, 50]
    }
)
```

Try 1: Error: "KeyError: 'Price'"

```
np.where(
    df['Price'] == 55,
    df['Color'].value_counts()
)
```

Try 2: "KeyError: 'Price'"

```
df.loc[(df['Price'] == 55), df['Category'].value_counts()]
```

Try 3: "KeyError: 'Category'"

```
df['Category'].value_counts()[df['Price'] == 55]
```

Does anyone know why this does not work?

Comment: there is no category column in the DF above.  there is no DF2 defined either

Comment: Sorry about the DFs, those were a typo, I already corrected them. Answer did not help. I believe this is not working cause whatever i'm doing is for dfs, and `values_count()` makes a Series. So they are not compatible. Not sure what to do tho

Answer (score 0):

```
# filter rows where price eq 55, 
# count the color

out=df.loc[df['Price'].eq(55)]['Color'].value_counts()
out
```

```
red      1
green    1
Name: Color, dtype: int64
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I get `Series([], Name: Color, dtype: int64)`
My code is:
`out=df.loc[df['Price'].eq(23)]['Color'].value_counts()`
`print(out)`

Comment: how your expected result looks like?

Comment: @JoseDanielRojas, if you share the expected output, i.e., if not series then how it should return will greatly help me tweak the answer.